# How to include a specific font family not found at Google Fonts?

Tags: html, css

I want to use a font type called Daniel, but it's not found at Google Fonts.
Is there any way to use this type of font at my web site?

Comment: Did you try researching this before asking?

Comment: Download the Webfont Kit and and follow the instructions
https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/daniel

Answer (score 4):

You have to download fonts files and delcare a font-face in your css.
You can check [www.w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_font-face_rule.asp) for more details. Here is an example :

```
@font-face {
    font-family: Montserrat;
    src: url("./fonts/Montserrat-Regular.otf");
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}@font-face {
    font-family: Montserrat;
    src: url("./fonts/Montserrat-Bold.otf");
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
}@font-face {
    font-family: Montserrat Light;
    src: url("./fonts/Montserrat-Light.otf");
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}@font-face {
    font-family: Montserrat Thin;
    src: url("./fonts/Montserrat-Thin.otf");
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}@font-face {
    font-family: Montserrat Medium;
    src: url("./fonts/Montserrat-Medium.otf");
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}@font-face {
    font-family: Montserrat SemiBold;
    src: url("./fonts/Montserrat-SemiBold.otf");
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: Note that you will want multiple formats as the answer states to support different browsers. Assuming you don't have all these, you can use a service like [Transfonter](https://transfonter.org/) to create them for you (along with the necessary CSS).

Comment: also You should rather search for woff format or use some software to make it ... otf and ttf are not supported by IE until EDGE